# Javascript regex help not match char

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making my own markdown editor, and it does bold and italic much like stack overflow:

```
// **bold**
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*\\*(.+?)\\*\\*", "g"), '<strong>$1</strong>');

// *italic*
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*(.+?)\\*", "g"), '<em>$1</em>');
```

The problem is now that if someone want to have a series of asterix in their text like:

> If you want to do A * B * C then...

This would come out as:

> A *B* C

Stackoverflow does it well where the asterix only work if they are not touching a space character afterwards.  Eg:

```
** Bold ** = not bold
**Bold** = bolded
* Italic * = not italic
*Italic* = italics
```

So I try to add in `[^ ]` to make it match a non space character which is a bit buggy:

```
// **bold**
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*\\*(.+?)\\*\\*", "g"), '<strong>$1</strong>');

// *italic*
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*[^ ](.+?)[^ ]\\*", "g"), '<em>$1</em>');
```

This seems to strip a character off the start and end of $1 but apart from that it works.  How can I modify my regex so both bold and italic are only activated if the text contained within is not padded by any spaces?

### Edit

```
// **bold**
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*\\*([^ ](.+?)[^ ])\\*\\*", "g"), '<strong>$1</strong>');

// *italic*
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*([^ ](.+?)[^ ])\\*", "g"), '<em>$1</em>');
```

But the test case:

```
this ** shouldnt be bold ** ewfwef
```

Renders as

> this * *shouldnt be bold* * ewfwef

Comment: Have you tried `[^\s]` instead of `[^ ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the character classes inside the capture group:

```
([^ ].+?[^ ])
```

or a bit shorter (and considers all white spaces):

```
(\S.+?\S)
```

Comment: Thanks Felix!   I edited question, it works but the bold one isn't really working do you know what I need to do?

Comment: @TomGullen: Try `([^\s*].+?[^\s*])`